# How to merge two object TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have two objects:

```
let a = [{id: 1, selected: false, key: "plan"}];
let b = [{id: 1, selected: true, key: "plan", "text": "aaaa"}, {id: 2, selected: true}];
```

I need to merge them and get:

```
let c = [{id: 1, selected: true, key: "plan", "text": "aaaa"}, {id: 2, selected: true}];
```

My main purpose to rewrite default object on modified

I have tried:

```
let c = {...a, ...b};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce` in order to replace the data that is being fetched from server.

Below I have simulated different scenarios considering `a` as the original array and `b` & `c` as the responses from the server

```js
let a = [{ id: 1, selected: false, key: 'plan' }];
let b = [
  { id: 1, selected: true, key: 'plan', text: 'aaaa' },
  { id: 2, selected: true },
];

const mergeArrays = (array1, array2) => {
  array2 = array2 || [];
  array1 = array1 || [];
  return Object.values([...array1, ...array2].reduce((result, obj) => {
    result = {
      ...result,
      [obj.id]: {...obj}
    }
    return result;
  }, {}))
};

//Consider you got the response from server 
//a -> Original array,  b -> Response from serer
console.log(mergeArrays(a, b))

//Response from server is null or []
console.log(mergeArrays(a, null))

//original array is empty but there's a response from server
console.log(mergeArrays([], b))

//Consider there is completely a different object in the array received from the server than the one defined in the original array 
let c = [{ id: 2, selected: true, key: 'plan' }];

console.log(mergeArrays(a, c))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you must first determine which one is biggest then, if b is bigger than a:

```js
let a = [{id: 1, selected: false, key: "plan"}];
let b = [{id: 1, selected: true, key: "plan", "text": "aaaa"}, {id: 2, selected: true}];

let bigger = a.length > b.length ? a : b;
let shorter = a.length < b.length ? a : b; 

console.log(bigger.map(x => ({...x, ...shorter.find(y => y.id === x.id)})))
```

Comment: What is I can not say which one biggest?

Comment: I jsut know if object comes from server and not null  I have to overwrite on this object

Answer (score -1):

You can use destructure:
`let c = [...a,...b];`

Comment: What if `b` is null or empy array?

Comment: If it is an empty array its ok. If it is null or undefined you have to check it before.

Comment: This solution doesn't provide the output that's being asked by the OP.